# How to make a query for each year?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a query for the question: In each year which producer sold the most car? I could write a query where I define the year, but what is the way to list it automatically for each year?

```
SELECT producer, COUNT(type) AS counter
FROM `car` 
INNER JOIN producer ON car.producer= producer.id 
WHERE produce_year = 2000 
GROUP BY type 
ORDER BY COUNT(type) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Please provide sample data

Comment: You'll need to introduce the produce_year in your select. Your group by is incorrect, it should be grouping by producer.

Comment: I think the ranking should be done on the value the producer generated from selling the cars. Please provide the schema of your tables and some sample data if possible.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Add year to the `GROUP BY`. Remove the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT producer, produce_year, COUNT(type) AS counter
FROM `car` 
INNER JOIN producer ON car.producer = producer.id 
GROUP BY producer, produce_year 
ORDER BY COUNT(type) DESC
```

Comment: How will this return only one producer per year?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, is that the question? No sample data and no expected result made me guess, and perhaps I'm wrong...

Comment: _In each year which producer sold the most car?_

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I'll wait for sample data and the expected result. And to  know which MySQL version OP is using.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select * from (SELECT producer, COUNT(type) as cou
,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY produce_year ORDER BY COUNT(type)) AS myrank
FROM car c 
INNER JOIN producer p ON c.producer= p.id  
GROUP BY  produce_year) 
where myrank=1;
```